# Windows 10 as host VMware workstation 12 Player no bridge adapter (vmnet0)

Tags: windows, networking

I'm running Windows 10 OS and want to replicate what I had in Windows 7, meaning, a number of Virtual Machines running different OSs.

VMWare states that it supports Windows 10 as host for VMWare Workstation 12.

So far, I was unable to use network Bridge, and hence the guest machines cannot connect to the network, nor can be accessed (as servers) from outside my computer (as they used to be when running Windows 7 as the host).

I should add that, when looking at the network adapters, there were none initially till I REPAREed the VM installation. Now I can see VMnet1 and VMnet8 (which as far as I recall are for NAT and Host Only connection types). Also, I'm running Kaspersky AV.

What I tried:

1) Edit the adapters (Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings -> Properties [for LAN connection] -> Install Service -> VMWare Bridge Protocol): Failed due to "Access Denied" (though my account has Admin rights).

2) Tried to search for the Virtual Network Editor in vain,

3) Searched the Web (a number of days already) without success,

4) Check VMWare KB without success.

Did anyone encountered the same issue and found a working solution (without the need to rollback my computer to Windows 7 of course).

Thanks.

Comment: I had similar problems and removed VMware completely using the registry wiper they provide

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Two things: First, I need to have the VMWare installed eventually. Do you mean uninstall, wipe registry and re-install? Second, could you provide the link to the "wiper" you are referring to?

Comment: Sure, you need to reinstall afterwards. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1308

Comment: @Marged, I followed all the steps and the result is still negative. NAT with DHCP works, bridge does not (still complaining that VMnet0 is not found).

Answer (score 1):

Kaspersky is your issue. Had the exact same problem and nothing I tried worked until I removed Kaspersky, removed Vmware, rebooted and reinstalled vmware.

On re-installation, you can see the VMWare bridge protocol has been installed and enabled on the adapters and network bridge works on the VM's.

You can also confirm by going to "network adapter" in the VM settings and clicking on configure adapters. When it's broken, nothing will appear. Once fixed, you should see a list of adapters.

I have reinstalled Kaspersky and bridging continues to work. I suspect Anti-Virus NDIS 6 filter on the adapters may have something to do with it.

Comment: Thanks @Doug for your feedback. I need to see what I'll since I cannot work without Kaspersky or the like. Will see and post here the results of my trial.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem happened to me after migrating from windows 7 to windows 10. Found out this [article in VMware kb](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2013496) that worked for me.

```
To reset the winsock protocol in the Windows virtual machine:
1.Open a command prompt with elevated privileges. For more information see Microsoft article Command Prompt: frequently asked questions
2.Run this command:
netsh winsock reset
The command prompt indicates to restart the machine after the command completes.
3.Restart the virtual machine.
4.Open a command prompt with elevated privileges. For more information see Microsoft article Command Prompt: frequently asked questions
5.Run this command:
netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt
6.Close the command prompt. 
7.Restart the virtual machine.
```

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as above. Kaspersky was creating the problem.

- Uninstall both vm and kaspersky.
- Then install vm and restart.
- After that install Kaspersky once again.

That should resolve the issue